# How to find the average of a column in a csv file?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, average

I am trying to find the average of a column in this csv file.
I managed to read the csv file:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

emp_code = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\V\\Desktop\\data science\\DS1_C4_S1_Numpy_PracticeBrief.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

emp_code

array([['1', '22'],
       ['2', '27'],
       ['3', '31'],
       ['4', '29'],
       ['5', '27'],
       ['6', '26'],
       ['7', '27'],
       ['8', '23'],
       ['9', '27'],
       ['10', '32'],
       ['11', '28'],
       ['12', '27'],
       ['13', '22'],
       ['14', '27'],
       ['15', '35'],
       ['16', '33'],
       ['17', '28'],
       ['18', '22'],
       ['19', '25'],
       ['20', '27'],
       ['21', '37'],
       ['22', '27'],
       ['23', '24'],
       ['24', '27'],
       ['25', '28'],
       ['26', '26'],
       ['27', '27'],
       ['28', '27'],
       ['29', '29'],
       ['30', '49'],
       ['31', '26'],
       ['32', '32'],
       ['33', '26'],
       ['34', '24'],
       ['35', '24'],
       ['36', '23'],
       ['37', '28'],
       ['38', '28'],
       ['39', '22'],
       ['40', '26'],
       ['41', '32'],
       ['42', '35'],
       ['43', '33'],
       ['44', '31'],
       ['45', '30'],
       ['46', '36'],
       ['47', '22'],
       ['48', '23'],
       ['49', '32'],
       ['50', '34']], dtype='<U2')
```

Now, I am trying to find the average age. I am not sure how to find it. is it `np.mean['Age']`?
Edit: I tried emp_code[:,1].mean() and it gave an error.
It was a type error so I am not able to understand the cause behind it.

Comment: First row looks like header, try passing `skip_header=1` to `genfromtxt`, and use `delimeter=','`, then  you would get a numpy array with two columns, first being `emp_code`, second being `Age`. Or you can look at `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: @Quang Hoang I have used skip_header=1. Then what do I do after that?

Comment: `emp_code[:,1].mean()` gives you average age.

Comment: @QuangHoang - OP has strings with "," (as the decimal point?). Also it looks like `emp_code` is a 1D array.

Comment: @not_speshal That `,` looks more like the delimiter from the csv. That's why I suggested using `delimiter=','` instead of `';'` as in his code.

Comment: @Jon - Can you please update the question with the array you get after incorporating QuangHoang's suggestions?

Comment: the array of OP emp_code is 1D array. each element is a string e.g. '1,22' , so `emp_code[:,1].mean()` doesn't work

Comment: @Quang Hoang I have used this "emp_code[:,1].mean()" and it gave "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type". I do not quite understand this?

Comment: @Rabinzel I am not very good at this...

Comment: Try passing `dtype=None`, you're forcing it to read the data as strings instead of numeric values right now.

Comment: @tazman Thanks a lot! I completely forgot that unicode forced into strings. I assume if I had not mentioned dtype it would be the same?

Comment: And thanks to everyone here for helping me. I am quite new to this and I hope to improve. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jon no offense. I just tried it myself and noticed it doesn't work. So the solution was `dtype=None` ?

Comment: @Rabinzel Yup, that was the mistake. I was suppose to set it as dtype=None and I was able to get the average. I guess dtype=unicode made it into a string. And none taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue with datatype. You may need to *typecast*(convert) that or read floats as datatype from the text file.

To read it as floats from the text file:

```
emp_code = genfromtxt('C:\\Path\\to\\csv\\DS1_C4_S1_Numpy_PracticeBrief.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float64)
mean_age = emp_code[:,1].mean()
```

This code can help you with converting the numpy array to float and get the average age.

```
emp_code = np.asarray(emp_code, dtype=np.float64)
mean_age = emp_code[:,1].mean()
```

Comment: This is what I figured as well. Thanks for you answer though.